# how to set a default fragment at runtime in Navigation drawer that is created by android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

Below is the `MainActivity` class generated by android studio navigation drawer activity which contains 3 fragments named home, gallery, and slideshow and how can I change the default fragment at runtime

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

            }
        });

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,R.id.nav_home)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the default fragment at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from the mobile_navigation.xml file :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation2"
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">
```

You can change the destination by changing the app:startDestination, in this case, it's starting from nav_home.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the first/default fragment (start destination) must be set within the `navGraph` using `app:startDestination` attribute, otherwise you'll get a `RuntimeException` of `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment`.

So, the answer to your question: You can't set the ***default*** fragment programmatically because you've to set it first at xml. But what you can do is to navigate from the default `startDestination` to another destination fragment in `onCreate()` method before the default fragment is shown to the user.

The [`NavController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController) is the responsible for navigating among the fragment destinations in the `navGraph`.

There are several overloaded versions of `navigate()` method in `NavController` class that allow you navigate between fragments.

For instance to set the transaction to the Gallery fragment, you can pass its id to [`navigate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(int)) method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_gallery);
...
```